# Android and SQLite: Trigger is not updating?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I'm programming in Android and I'm facing a problem when I try to insert a value.
I have 2 tables, GASTOS and DESPESAS.
Every time I insert a row in DESPESAS I have a TRIGGER to update a field in GASTOS, col_DESPESA (but this is not happening) although **despesa.getQuantia()** has the right value.

**getGasto()** is a method that returns a Object gasto after read the values in database. So when I do the Log to check what gasto.getDespesa has, it should returns the value that was in the trigger but it doesn't, it returns me 0.

My code:

```
String UPDATE_TRIGGER =
                "CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS update_trigger" +
                        "  AFTER INSERT ON " + TABLE_DESPESA + " FOR EACH ROW" +
                        "  BEGIN " +
                        "UPDATE " + TABLE_GASTOS +
                        "  SET " + col_DATA_MODIF + " = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AND " +
                        col_DESPESA + "= "+despesa.getQuantia()+
                        "  WHERE " + col_MES + " = '"+gasto.getMes()+"' AND " + col_ANO + " = "+gasto.getAno()+" ;"
                        + "END;" ;

db.execSQL(UPDATE_TRIGGER);

gasto=getGasto();

        Log.d("LOG","getDespesa->"+gasto.getDespesa());
```

Can you please help me? Why **gasto.getDespesa()** returns me 0?

Comment: despesa.getQuantia(): is this a java call? I think that does not work. Should be TABLE_DESPSA.QUANTITY or so.

Comment: @GunnarBernstein thanks for comment but the fact is that I changed all my code and I got what I wanted, so no more issue :)